# Relocation error after 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH'

Tags: c++, conda, libstdc++

Running a python file threw the following error:

```
File "/home/<username>/miniconda3/<gitrepo>/eval.py", line 13, in <module> from dataset import dtu_jiayu
File "/home/<username>/miniconda3/<gitrepo>/dtu_jiayu.py", line 10, in <module> from dataset.utils import *
File "/home/<username>/miniconda3/<gitrepo>/utils.py", line 13, in <module> from PIL import Image
File "/home/<username>/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 100, in <module> from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found
```

The error comes from an import inside the Image.py file of the package PIL (pillow).
According to several other posts, adding a path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH by typing

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/<username>/miniconda3/lib/
```

should solve the problem.

However after I did so, basic linux commands (i.e. ls) did not work anymore and the terminal said:

```
ls: relocation error: /lib64/libacl.so.1: symbol getxattr, version ATTR_1.0 not defined in file libattr.so.1 with link time reference
```

I am using the cluster of my university and working in the base environment of miniconda.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you [mixing channels](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels)? That is, are all the packages from **defaults** or did you install something from **conda-forge** channel? Generally, one should not need to manipulate `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for Conda packages to work.

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a separate environment. Seems as if the base environment made problems.